# Trying to post a serialized form and number to controller in ASP.NET / MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post a serialized form and an id to my controller.

Controller Method:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult MoveOrderItem_Create_From_List([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, List<MoveOrderItemDTO> moiToCreateList, long assignmentUID)
        {
            if (moiToCreateList != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            IUser user = LoggedInUserProvider.getUser();
            //Get the contact Id that is editing

            foreach (MoveOrderItemDTO item in moiToCreateList)
            {
                item.EditContactId = user.ContactId;
            }


            moveOrderViewModel.upsertOrderItemsTransaction(moiToCreateList.Cast<IMoveOrderItem>().ToList());


        }

        return Json(new[] { moiToCreateList }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

My javascript:

```
function MoveOrderPost() {

var moAss = $("#moAssForm").serialize()

$.post("MoveOrder/MoveOrderAssignement_Create", moAss,
function (data)
{

           if (data.Errors === null) {
        var assignID = data.Data[0].Id;

        var moAssItemList = $("#moAssItemForm").serialize()

        var url = "MoveOrderItem/MoveOrderItem_Create_From_List";
        valuesToPost = moAssItemList,"assignmentUID:" + assignID ;
               debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: valuesToPost,
            success: function (data)
            {
                //data - response from server
                if (data.Errors === null)
                {


                }
                else
                {
                    //TODO - Add error handling
                }
            },

        });



    }
    else
    {
        //TODO - Add error handling
    }


});
```

If I take out the AssignmentUID param in the controller and make it,

```
data: moAssItemList
```

, the list comes through.

I have also tried...

```
valuesToPost = {   "moiToCreateList": +moAssItemList, "assignmentUID": +assignID }
```

In this case the assignmentUID comes through to the controller but the list is empty. I am sure it is probably a syntax thing, but I can not figure out what I am missing. I have looked at many other posts and tried the syntax specified, but I seem to only be able to get the list or the UID not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically add that to the querystring

```
var assignID = data.Data[0].Id; 
$.ajax({
          url: url+"?assignmentUID="+assignID ,
          data:$("#moAssItemForm").serialize(),
          //Existing code    
});
```